# Kendo for MVC Grid - Create success

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if there is any way to validate if I can specify a success action after creating successfully using Kendo Grid for MVC.

I have the following line for Create action, and I would like to add a validation if it was succcess display a message.

```
 .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Customer"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I am not sure if it is the best one but it works.

I added the following event

```
 .Events(events =>
            {
              events.RequestEnd("checkResult");
            })
```

Then I created a javascript function

```
 function evaluateResult(e)
 {
         if (e.type == "create" && e.response.Errors==null)  { ... //success}
 }
```